# How do I send BYTE* to c# interop with SendMessage?

Tags: c#, c++, sendmessage

How do I sent a data* and then read it from c# as `byte[]` with sendmessage?

```
SendMessage((HWND)fatwindow, OnRecvMessage, ??, ??);
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, but normally this is done with the WM_COPYDATA window message.

there should be quite a lot of examples, for example here: http://boycook.wordpress.com/2008/07/29/c-win32-messaging-with-sendmessage-and-wm_copydata/